# ‘To be concentrated’ usage

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis, passive-voice

Recently I have heard many people say that somebody needs ‘to be concentrated’ on something.

Am I right in saying that this is being used incorrectly?

Comment: you should probably include the logic for your reasoning too.

Comment: I've never heard it used that way, that someone needs to be *concentrated* on something.  What I hear is that someone needs to be *concentrating* on something.  That said, were I to hear someone say, "He needs to be concentrated on something," I would probably construe that it means that somebody needs to make him concentrate, if not himself, someone else.  I'm not sure that that's right, but that's what I would gather from someone saying "concentrated" instead of "concentrating."

Comment: @user070221:  At the very bottom of your link page, it specifically says,   "Be Careful!  Don't say that someone 'is concentrated on' something."  I think whoever uses that incorrect expression is meaning "focused on s.th."

Comment: Effort needs to be "concentrated", people need to "concentrate".

Answer (score 2):

Collins Dictionary has the following usage note on ***[concentrate on](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/concentrated+on)*** and ***be concentrated on:***

> ***If you concentrate on something, you give special attention to it, rather than to other things.***
>
> - Concentrate on your driving.
> - He believed governments should concentrate more on education.
> - If someone is concentrating on something, they are spending most of their time or energy on it.
> - They are concentrating on saving lives.
> - One area Dr Gupta will be concentrating on is tourism.

***Be Careful!***

> ***Don't say that someone 'is concentrated on' something.***

***[Be concentrated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be%20concentrated)*** has the following  usage, as suggested by M-W:

> to be mainly found (in a place):
>
> - *The population is concentrated near the coast. Power was concentrated in the hands of a few rich men.*